# Does MmUnmapLockedPages suppose to free virtual address

Tags: c++, memory, kernel, driver

I am **sharing a memory** between my driver and application. 
After I did *Allocating* and *Mapping*, I clean up with *Unmapping* and *Free*.
I found that *Allocating and Mapping* would allocate a *brand new* virtual memory page in the application, which can be accessed by both driver and application, but it does not disappear after I did the *clean up*.
I want to know if I should expect the the page to be free after I did clean up.

I saw that *MmAllocatePagesForMdlEx* and *MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache* will allocate a **brand new** page of virtual memory in application, which did not appear in the memory list before. After I **clean up** with *MmUnmapLockedPages* and *MmFreePagesFromMdl*, I **still see** that allocated memory in the list, which is still able to be **read and write** by the VC++ debugger and application.
I have think of if the clean up failed, but another thing makes me confused. The clean up would **zero** the memory page, which makes me think it actually is working.
And there is one more thing I did. I use a tool called CE to read the memory but the result is it **cannot** be read. CE is using **ReadProcessMemory** to read the memory. So I again get confused.
To summarize, I did

- Allocate - MmAllocatePagesForMdlEx
- Map - MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache
- Unmap - MmUnmapLockedPages
- Free - MmFreePagesFromMdl

The result is

- VC++ debugger can read the cleaned up memory
- Application itself can read the cleaned up memory
- CE which use standard API cannot read the cleaned up memory
- CE which use standard API can see the memory info in the memory list

The method I used to test reading cleaned up memory

- VC++ debugger - in memory tab, goto address
- Application - value = ^(ULONG64^)addr; //star disabled

The main code are as below:

```
mdl = MmAllocatePagesForMdlEx(least, most, least, totalBytes, MmCached, 0);
MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(mdl, NormalPagePriority);
MmUnmapLockedPages(userAddr, mdl);
MmFreePagesFromMdl(mdl);
```

I expected that after I did the last two code mentioned above, the allocated memory would be free because even the mapped physical memory is being free.
So again my question is, should I expect the cleaned up memory become No Access in application / usermode space.

Comment: Virtual memory is just a number in a pointer.  Accessing it is no different than reading or writing memory after a free call.  It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Problem solved. The clean up must be executed in system thread. What I did is calling the MmUnmapLockedPages and MmFreePagesFromMdl in a created thread. Thanks for your help